# how to package and reference text file in resources folder

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I have a spark project using scala and sbt. At one point it references a text file which I want to be packaged.
This is how it is referenced in the application source:

```
getClass.getResource("/myFile.txt")
```

This works fine running the source code with sbt run. But I want it to be packaged and deployed to a server.

In build.sbt, after some googling I have got this to work

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= directory("src/main/resources")
```

adding this meant that the myFile.txt appears in the resources folder in the package. created using

> sbt universal:packageBin

resulting folder structure:

```
target - universal - bin
                   - lib
                   - resources
```

however when I run my packaged application from bin/my-application.bat , I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/C:/Software/my-application-0.0.1/lib/my-application-0.0.1.jar!/myFile.txt;

Bear in mind I have zero experience of deploying scala or jvm based things so you may have to spoonfeed me the explanation

---

EDIT I later realised that the text file was in fact included in the .jar file.
the issue then was that getResource does not work in this case and I had to adapt my code to use getResourceAsStream

Comment: Are you getting whatever is present in resources in your jar file(jar created after packing it under target directory)? In your system after building jar(SBT jar in target) try to unzip it using winzip and try to find whatever is present in your resource folder without compiling. Your file should be present in your jar file(SBT jar which you are running) classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can have multiple reasons.

### Include files in your resulting jar

You added this line, which is not correct

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= directory("src/main/resources")
```

The `src/main/resources` directory is the `resourceDirectory in Compile` and the contents are always present in the package **jar** file (not the zip!). So I would highly recommend removing this snippet as you will have your files twice in your classpath.

The `mappings in Universal` ([documentation link](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/universal.html#getting-started-with-universal-packaging)) define the content of the created package (with `universal:packageBin` the zip file). I assume that you are using the [JavaAppPackaging plugin](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/archetypes/java_app/index.html), which configures your entire build. By default all dependencies and your actual build artifact end up in the `libs` folder. Start scripts are being place in `bin`.

The start scripts also create a valid classpath, which includes all libraries in `lib` and nothing else by default.

**TL;DR** You simply put your files in `src/main/resources` and they will be available on the classpath.

### How to find files on the classpath

You posted this snippet

```
 getClass.getResource("/myFile.txt")
```

This will lookup a file called `myFile.txt` in the roots of your classpath. As in the comment suggested you should open your application jar file and find a text file `myFile.txt` at the root, otherwise it won't be found.

hope that helps,
Muki